# Prove that $\max\{|x_i|: 1 \leq i \leq n\} \leq \|\vec{x}\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i|$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If $\|\vec{x}\|$ denotes the Euclidean Norm of $\vec{x} \in R^n$, show that 
$$
\max\left\{|x_i|: 1 \leq i \leq n\right\} \leq \|\vec{x}\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i|
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try applying the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) on the left side and the [Triangle Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) on right side.